# Why is the parent path of a selected file not usable?

Tags: android, android-file

The following code is used to launch a file manager to allow the user to select a file:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CUSTOM_FOLDER);
```

If the user selects file foo.txt in folder Download, the returned file's path is

```
/document/2071-13DB:Download/foo.txt
```

There is no problem in reading that file. When the app tries to write a text file (foo_new.txt) to folder "/document/2071-13DB:Download", it gets the following exception:

```
Error:Directory '/document/2071-13DB:Download' could not be created.
```

Could anyone shed some light on this?  I am trying to allow the user to select a folder for the app to save files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following code is used to launch a file manager to allow the user to select a file

No, it is not. It is used to get a piece of content, from any activity that support that particular `Intent` structure.

> If the user selects file foo.txt in folder Download, the returned file's path is

You are not getting a file. You are getting a `Uri` to a piece of content. In particular, I strongly suspect that this `Uri` has a `content` scheme. In that case, the path is meaningless to you.

> When the app tries to write a text file (foo_new.txt) to folder "/document/2071-13DB:Download", it gets the following exception

That is not a folder. From your standpoint, that is a random series of characters.

For example, the URL of this Web page is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337012/why-is-the-parent-path-of-a-selected-file-not-usable`. You can use an HTTP client to read the contents of that page. However, if you try using Java's `File` object to write a new file to `/questions/39337012/` on your computer, you will find that this will not work, because you do not have a `/questions/39337012/` folder on your computer. Here, the URL points to content that is not on your computer's filesystem.

Similarly, you cannot perform string manipulations of a portion of a `Uri` and come up with another `Uri` that you can use. A `Uri` does not have to point to a file on the filesystem.

> I am trying to allow the user to select a folder for the app to save files.

Use [a directory-chooser library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/35), then.

Or, on Android 5.0+ devices, use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, which is part of the Storage Access Framework. From there, use `DocumentFile` to create new folders, create new content in those folders, etc., all using `Uri` values without trying to decipher the pieces of the `Uri` values (e.g., `getPath()`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt elucidation.  Here is how the app gets the file path: intentData.getData().getPath() where intentData is onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentData).

Comment: @Hong: Again, that's not a file path, any more than `/questions/39337012/why-is-the-parent-path-of-a-selected-file-not-usable` is a file path. If the scheme of the `Uri` were `file`, then `getPath()` *does* return a file path, though perhaps not one that is useful to you (e.g., points to something on removable storage).

Comment: Thank you again for the clarification.  The URI is: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/2071-13DB%3ADownload%2Ffoo.txt